# "Help me find a paper"-type questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, closed-questions

Recently, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985372/how-can-i-have-a-copy-of-this-old-paper) question was closed as "not being about maths". I think that this closure is worthy of further discussion.

Basically, I believe that finding papers (especially old ones, or translations of foreign ones) is difficult, and is an important skill in any subject. However, with maths it is a skill best learned from other mathematicians (we have MathSciNet, for example). Therefore, I believe that this question should have been either,

1. Left open.
2. Migrated to MathOverflow.
3. Migrated to Academia.SE

I do not know how MathOverflow would treat such a question, and I do not know if migrating to Academia.SE would yield an answer. However, either option is better than simply "closure".

Also, I do not see how such a question is less about mathematics than any other reference request...

> What do you think should have happened to such a question, and why?

For a personal anecdote about why I think asking others about finding papers is good: In the first year of my PhD I spent a long time trying to find a pair of 1940s Russian papers, from a journal which didn't seem to exist until 1967. I managed to track down a MathSciNet article, but it was in German. My library and librarian were of no help. In the end, I found a recent citation and e-mailed the authors, who sent me a link to the original paper and a 1980s English paper which proved an equivalent result in a different way, and they gave me a brief summary of the difference between "USSR: Sbornik" (Russian Journal, since 1860s) and "Matematicheskii Sbornik" (English translation of said journal, since 1967).

Comment: It was posted to MO (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185045/how-can-i-have-a-copy-of-this-old-paper) and got an answer.

Comment: As there are no comments to the effect of "don't double post", and going by the close reason, I think it is fair to assume (for the moment, unless one of the closers corrects me) that the double-posting was *not* the reason for the closure, but that the actual question was.

Comment: FWIW, I believe the question is certainly more on-topic here than on Academia.SE.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the question was closed because of the double-posting; I just thought the information might be of interest. Well, also I found it curious that the question would be closed on m.se but answered on MO.

Comment: The link to this reference material was also posted by AStudent in the comments 2 hours after the OP posted here in our actual MSE post. The MO answer beat that comment by a substantial time, and closure here made perfect sense. I recall hitting skip in review queue on this. Had I researched, I may or may not have seen it as a time simultaneous cross post. Reasonably hard to find reference requests for antiquated material qualify as good questions here in my convinced opinion. I am familiar with where this was found, but a google search might not get many people to this piece of literature.

Comment: @Gerry Sorry, my comment wasn't because I thought you were implying that. Rather, I was afraid that someone might claim that that was the close reason, so I thought I would nip that chain of thought in the bud.

Comment: This seemed contrary to the other uses of the [meta-tag:reference], so I removed it.

Answer (score 9):

Many such questions have been asked in the past - just have look on the result of this [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=find+paper+reference+site:math.stackexchange.com) or similar search [on the main site](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[reference-request]+find+paper). From what I have seen, I'd say that they were generally well-received. Such questions also seem to be common [on MathOverflow](http://www.google.com/search?q=find+paper+reference+site:mathoverflow.net).

Personally I do not have anything against questions asking for finding individual papers. (Although I would understand downvoting or even closing a question where it was very easy to find the paper - for lack of research effort.)

But I think that it might be useful to have also more general questions. (For example if I look for an old paper from Topology and Its Applications I might add to my question also something like this, to make the question more general: *I see that the volumes since 2000 are available on Elsevier website. Is there a way to find papers from older volumes?*<sup>1</sup>) Or maybe even if the question is not asked in a general way, answerer should mention how and where they were able to find the paper (in the [teach how to fish](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime) spirit).

Or even some post collecting various resources, where journals can be found, might be useful. The following question is formulated like this: [Finding a paper](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40762/finding-a-paper) (It also mentions the specific paper which the OP was after, but it is formulated as a general question about finding papers.)

<sup>1</sup>This is a fictional example, all volumes of [Topol. Appl.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology_and_its_Applications) seem to be available online.