# How to get articles when already graduated and signed out from university?

Tags: discussion

I was looking for the article "Kotzig's conjecture on generalized friendschip graphs" from J.A. Bondy. Since I graduated at the UvA and signed out, there is no possibility anymore to take it from e.g. the sites sciencedirect or researchgate. My brother does still have an account at the University of Leiden, but the articles there are only from 1988 on, while this one is from 1985.

Such a thing can happen once more. Is there a way to overcome this? Otherwise it would be very weird: I got a graduation and thereafter I can't read all articles anymore??
Could anyone sent me that article for once?

Comment: In the Olden Days, the way to do this would be to travel to a university, go to their library in person, and read the article while you are in the library.

Comment: In general, one thing you might try is emailing the authors and asking nicely for a preprint, though in this case, the professor in question does not appear to be online anywhere, and it's also an ethical gray area to be circumventing e.g. ScienceDirect's paywalls.

Comment: Your brother can also request the articles from any other university in the Netherlands through the Leiden University Library; he should get access instantly if some other university has a digital copy. Otherwise it may take a few days to deliver a physical copy. Note that Leiden University does allow alumni lifelong access to their entire library. Your brother made a good choice in that respect.

Comment: Somewhat related post on the main site: [Finding a paper](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40762). (You might have a look also [on the linked posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/40762).) There are a few related discussions here on meta: 
[Is it proper to request a specific paper here?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17469),
[“Help me find a paper”-type questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17127),
[To what extent should copyrighted material be made available on math.se?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/529)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending you a copy is likely illegal in many countries.

The situation is indeed weird, but to read articles, I for one have no other choice than pay for various subscribtions - and it's not cheap. My employer also have a few subscrbtions that I can use.

It's also possible to purchase only one article: apparently the one you want is 31.50$.

If you don't want to pay yourself, ask your current institution or employer if it can buy it for you.

Comment: Now that I think about the 31.50 $, maybe having no access is not so weird, because for being a student one has to pay 2000 euros each year instead. Thanks for your answer, I will go on looking for a shortcut.

Comment: The issue with paying >30 dollars for an article (here, that's $2 per page, which the author sees none of) is that you need to be darned sure that you need it! When I'm reading papers I so often search through dozens of them, having to access each of them, to find the one I'm after, and even then my need for the final paper is superficial (e.g. finding the correct statement of a theorem). Note: I offer no alternative. Just complaints.

Comment: @user1729 Agreed. But for those who are out of academia, there isn't really an alternative. We can only hope for a better future: open archives, or generalize offerings such as JSTOR (pay for a given number of articles in pdf + read freely online). Or even knowledge free for all. But right now, we have to pay, and choose carefuly.